# header menu link not showing when user logged in react redux koa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am newbie in React, Redux and I am learning it.

**My problem is:**

In my application, I have shown successfully a new header link i.e. Download Report when user logged in but when the page is REFRESHED. The header link is not showing when user logged IN but shows when we refresh the page.

I am using React and Redux and Koa as framework.

Similarly, when user logged out, the header link is not disappearing but when refreshed, it disappears.

Can you provide me with some suggestions regarding that. I have searched it online but all invain.

Thanks

Comment: Any code? Show the header component, actions and reducer, probably you are not dispatching the new reducer state

Comment: Any code? Show the header component, actions and reducer, probably you are not dispatching the new reducer state